# How does std::sort modify the backing type?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, iterator

When I call `sort` on a `vector` of `double`s using the `begin()` and `end()` iterators how does the `sort` function modify the original `vector` to contain the sorted values?

I though iterators simply represented a value, so how could they cause the original `vector` to get modified?

```
vector<double> nums = {10.33, 20.44, 60.77};
sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(); // how does the original nums get changed?
```

Comment: It doesn't represent a value. It represents a position in the vector.

Comment: It can change(swap) the elements' value by dereference the iterator.

Comment: @NickyC that makes sense. But how does it modify the vector?

Comment: An iterator is any object that points to some object within a range and has the ability to iterate through the elements. The most obvious iterator is a pointer. If you know how pointers work then you have your answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao Ah yes I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iterator doesn't represent the value, it represents some position in a container, stream, or stream buffer. Essentially, they are a generalization of pointers. Some iterators will let you modify what they are iterating over using indirection (`*it`).

In the simplest case, it could simply be a pointer. Consider this code:

```
vector<double> nums = {10.33, 20.44, 60.77};
double* it = &nums[0]; //get the address of the first element
++it; //increment the pointer
*it = 42; //assign 42 to nums[1]
```

An iterator provides much the same functionality (depending on the type of iterator).

```
vector<double> nums = {10.33, 20.44, 60.77};
vector<double>::iterator it = nums.begin();//get an iterator to the first element
++it; //increment the iterator
*it = 42; //assign 42 to nums[1]
```

Comment: In this example (and in most examples), an iterator does, indeed, represent a position in a container. But it **in fact** represents a position in a **sequence**; containers are one way of creating sequences, but they are not the only way. `std::istream_iterator`, for example, is an iterator that points at a sequence of characters even though there is no underlying container.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I don't want to distract from the answer, which addresses the question as asked, so I won't take this further, but it's only partly fixed. The key abstraction is the **sequence**, independent of **any** particular type. Imagine a type `my_iter` that simply holds an integer, whose `operator*` returns `std::rand()`, whose `operator++()` increments the integer, and whose `operator==(my_iter)` compares the integer values of the two `my_iter` objects. That's a sketch of a valid input iterator; `for (my_iter it(0); it != my_iter(5); ++it)` iterates through a **sequence** of 5 random values.